# Dynamic add slide in flexslider carousel

Tags: jquery, slider, slideshow, flexslider

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="flexslider carousel mtop20">
    <ul class="slides col-md-12" id="div_portion">
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery code**

Here I append div dynamically in flexslider. It append successfully but got Next and Previous button disabled.

```
$div = "<li> Content here </li>";
$("#div_portion").append($div);
slider = $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    animationLoop: false,
    itemWidth : 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    minItems: 1
  });
```

My Question is how to add div dynamically in flexslider with proper working mode?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XXzpW/24/)**

Html

```
<div id="slider" class="flexslider carousel mtop20">
    <ul class="slides col-md-12" id="div_portion">
    </ul>
</div>
<a id="add" href="javascript:void(0);">Add</a>
```

JS

```
$('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel"
});

$("#add").click(function(){
    div = "<li> How are you</li>";
    $('#slider').data('flexslider').addSlide($(div));

});

// Custom stuff
var saved1;
saved1 = $('<li>Hello</li>');
$('#slider').data('flexslider').addSlide($(saved1));
saved1 = $('<li>World</li>');
$('#slider').data('flexslider').addSlide($(saved1));
```

Comment: `TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined`

Comment: `Added two times new appended div`

Comment: You are not supposed to `append` the `div`. `.addSlide` function does that job. http://jsfiddle.net/XXzpW/24/

Comment: the fiddle link is now a 404

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#slider').data('flexslider').addSlide(ListItem);  
 $('#carousel').data('flexslider').addSlide(ListItem);
```

Both of these work. The image needs to be converted in the code behind to  Convert.ToBase64String if you're using byte[] for your image file data. then in the src, src='data:image/png;base64,' + theNameOfYourByteStream.

Neither of them will work when there is no listItems in the carousel or slider. You will need to initalize the slider and carousel after you add a list item>img to it.

```
$('#nameOfYour<ul>').append(<li><img></li>)
```

Then you'll need to run the init of the flexslider

```
    var carousel = $('#carousel').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        itemWidth: 210,
        itemMargin: 5,
        asNavFor: '#slider'
    });
```

The functionality is the same for the flexslider, but the enlarge, or focus on the image in the "slider" does not work with the new slides, when you click on the new slide in the "carousel".

A jsFiddle for the click focus event not happening already exists. 
http://jsfiddle.net/XXzpW/5/

```
// From example page:
$('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 100,
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
});

$('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    sync: "#carousel"
});

// Custom stuff
var saved1;
var saved2;

function removeRose() {
    saved1 = $('#carousel').find('.rose');
    saved2 = $('#slider').find('.rose');
    $('#carousel').data('flexslider').removeSlide($('.rose'));
    $('#slider').data('flexslider').removeSlide($('.rose'));
};

function addRose() {
    $('#carousel').data('flexslider').addSlide(saved1);
    $('#slider').data('flexslider').addSlide($(saved2));
};

$('#menu').on('click', 'li:first', function () {
    removeRose();
});

$('#menu').on('click', 'li:last', function () {
    addRose();
});
```