# Can I reinitialize Flexslider?

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I want to add slides dynamically to the flexslider but flexslider isn't working for dynamically added slides.

```
$(".clone").click(function() {
    var th = "#sendFeedback";
    $(th).clone(true).appendTo(".slides");
    $('.flexslider').data('flexslider').setup(); 
});
```

Comment: You need to add slides using `addslide`, [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542147/dynamic-add-slide-in-flexslider-carousel)

Comment: it is working fine for 1 item but I am having 3 items on a page